# Can fabric tasks have names that are not valid Python function names?

Tags: python, fabric

I'd like my Fabric tasks to have hyphens (-) instead of underscores (_). For example, database-reset instead of database_reset. However, hyphens aren't permitted as Python function names.

Is it possible in Fabric to create tasks whose names do not exactly match the corresponding Python function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.1/usage/tasks.html#task-aliases):

```
@task(alias = 'database-reset')
def database_reset():
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Cat Plus Plus has the best solution to what you want to do. Tangentially, however, it is technically possible to have Python global variables (a function name is just a global variable) that don't conform to the usual rules by assigning to the `globals()` dictionary.

```
def foo_bar():
    print "foo-bar"

globals()["foo-bar"] = foo_bar

globals()["foo-bar"]()   # prints "foo-bar"
```

The syntax is not very nice, though, making it quite the hassle.